# SQLDeveloper removes spaces from a blankline when inserting or updating

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I execute the script (whithout comments and replacing the "." by spaces):

```
    SET SQLBLANKLINES ON
    UPDATE ANY_TABLE SET VARCHAR2_COLUMN='Hello
    .....  -- 1st empty line with trailing spaces
    Kitty
    ...' -- last empty line with trailing spaces
    WHERE ID='something';
```

it is saved in the database like:

```
    'Hello
      -- 1st empty line WITHOUT spaces
    Kitty
    ...' -- last empty line WITH trailing spaces
```

So the spaces in the 1st blankline are lost but not on the last one. And I am using "SET SQLBLANKLINES ON" !!

Can anybody explain me what I'm doing wrong? Or What misconception I have?

The problem is the same with an insert and is independent of using simple spaces or tabs.

In fact, thanks to [Alex Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266304/alex-poole), we can simplify the example:
Why are the next queries returning different value lengths?

```
    select length('Hello
    ......   --6 characters (spaces)
    Kitty') from dual;
    -- returns 12
    
    select length('Hello
    x.....  -- 6 characters (an 'x' + 5 spaces)
    Kitty') from dual;
    -- returns 18

    select length('Hello
    '||'......
    Kitty') from dual;
    -- returns 18
```

What I am using:

- SQLDeveloper 20.2.0.175
- Oracle database 19

The problem may be related to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565783/sqlplus-removes-trailing-spaces-in-clob-field-on-insert)

Comment: Interesting. It does the same in 21.4.0; you can see it more easily with `select length('<your value>') from dual` - which should be 21, but SQL Developer reports 16. As does SQL\*Plus. Or you can see it with `dump()`. (This shouldn't have anything to do with [`sqlblanklines`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-789EBD80-7C9F-486E-91B8-E3A994CA2663) though - nothing should alter the value of a string literal. With that off SQL\*Plus errors.)

Comment: I forgot to mention that like in the related question, the problem is avoided cutting the text and concatenating at the begining of the 1st blankline with '||'. But I think this is not a reasonable solution...

Answer (score 0):

The q'[]' function is your friend.

```
create table multiline_strings
 (id integer,
  words varchar2(256));
  
insert into multiline_strings (id, words) values
(
 1,
 q'[Hello
     
Kitty
   ]');
```

[image]

[See this question/answer - probably should close this as a duplicate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090072/insert-a-multiline-string-in-oracle-with-sqlplus/35656009)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not even working. Where are de 5 spaces of the blankline between Hello and Kitty?

Comment: Yes, I tried that (and just for fun `u''` and `n''`) in SQL Developer, SQL\*Plus and SQLcl and didn't see any change - it still treats a line of just spaces as empty. Kind of weird that the Java tools seem to have copied that from SQL\*Plus, and I haven't found any settings that help. (And it does seem to be a client problem, spaces are missing in the SQL log, and [it's OK in db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5f7e3a43fd8663f461afad2ac81fc5d8).)

Comment: oh heck, yeah where are the 5 spaces on the 2nd line...let me dig a bit more @AlexPoole